# Canopy 'Setting up your Canopy Environment' stage does not finish

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, enthought, canopy

I have a problem installing and operating **Enthought Canopy** on my PC with **Windows 10, 64 bit**.

After the installation stage, **'Setting up your Canopy Environment'** process lingers on 54% completion and does not end.

***Below*** is what I've tried :

> 1. Half-deleted and re-installed, Completely-deleted and re-installed Canopy.
> 2. As my User name contains non-ASCII, I ran `cmd` as administrator and typed
>      `msiexec /i "C:\canopydownload\canopy-1.7.4-win-64.msi" ALLUSERS=1`
>      and installed it for **all users**.
> 3. Changed some **Environment Variables**, including creating 
>      **CANOPY_CONFIG, HADOOP_HOME, JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME, PATH, PYTHONPATH**
>      on User side.
> 4. Set `C:\Program files\Canopy` as the environmental directory when I first operated Canopy as an administrator.
> 5. Checked whether Canopy User Python is my default Python by typing
>      `import sys; sys.prefix` and got
>      `C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64`
>      as a return value.

I've tried what I can think of for the past 3 days, but I'm stuck now.

Maybe one possible cause of this situation might be related to **Environment Variables** as I am not very good at those.

I want to hear your vision about this problem I have, and teach me how the EVs
are supposed to look like.

Thank you very much, whoever is reading this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

a) No need to uninstall/reinstall, but do a complete reset as described [here](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy).

b) Remove any references to Canopy, and to any other Python, from your PATH and PYTHONPATH environment variables. (See https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-)

c) Pay attention to [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python), but for now at least, do NOT add anything to your PATH.

d) Restart Canopy.

Hope this helps. If the problem persists, send your environment variables in an email to support@enthought.com. Be sure to refer to this SO question.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your support!
I gave up messing with non-ascii account and just created a new admin and set it as the only admin.
I read an article which told me that I should delete PYTHONPATH from my system variable and followed it.
Now both(pyspark on cmd & canopy operation) work perfect! Thanx a lot :)